# VBA macro to compare and add value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to do a macro for comparing values in one sheet with the other sheet and copying the unique values.

Explanation:
I get a bunch of IDs on weekly basis (Worksheet A). I want to see which of these IDs I already worked with in previous weeks (that list is on Worksheet B) and copy all the values from Worksheet A, that are new, to Worksheet B. You can see the wanted result as Worksheet B (after running the macro).

[image: sample]

I came up with some code but as I am new to VBA, it does not work and I am quite desperate now. Thanks for help anyone.

```
Sub Mymacro()
    Dim lastRowC As Long
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean
    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Dim GivenValues As Worksheet
    Dim IDs As Long
    Dim fVal As Range

    Set Data = Sheets("Worksheet B")
    Set GivenValues = Sheets("Worksheet A")
    lastRowC = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    IDs = GivenValues.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'imagine data in Worksheet B are in the first column

    For i = 1 To IDs
        Set fVal = Data.Range("A1:A" & lastRowC).Find(GivenValues.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If fVal Is Nothing Then
            GivenValues.Cells(i, 1).Copy
            Sheets(Data).Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=False
        Else: End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `WORKSHEETFUNCTION.COUNTIF` and then copy if the return is 0.  Also, `Range("A1").Select` you should prefix your ranges with sheets when referring to 2 and selecting.  No need for select, for example `Range("A1").End(xlDown).offset(1,0).pastespecial`

Answer (score 0):

The code would be like this.

```
 Sub Mymacro()

    Dim lastRowC As Long
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean
    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Dim GivenValues As Worksheet
    Dim IDs As Long
    Dim fVal As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB, rngT As Range
    Dim vR(), n As Long

        Set Data = Sheets("Worksheet B")
        Set GivenValues = Sheets("Worksheet A")

        lastRowC = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IDs = GivenValues.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = Data.Range("a1", "a" & lastRowC)

        With GivenValues
            vDB = .Range("a1", "a" & IDs)
        End With
'imagine data in Worksheet B are in the first column
            For i = 1 To IDs
                Set fVal = rngDB.Find(vDB(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If fVal Is Nothing Then
                        n = n + 1
                        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                        vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
                    End If
            Next i
            Set rngT = Data.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If n > 0 Then
                rngT.Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
            End If
    End Sub
```

If you want to except duplication, look next code.

```
Sub Mymacro()

    Dim lastRowC As Long
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean
    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Dim GivenValues As Worksheet
    Dim IDs As Long
    Dim fVal As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB, rngT As Range
    Dim vR(), n As Long
    Dim X As New Collection

        Set Data = Sheets("Worksheet B")
        Set GivenValues = Sheets("Worksheet A")

        lastRowC = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IDs = GivenValues.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = Data.Range("a1", "a" & lastRowC)

        With GivenValues
            vDB = .Range("a1", "a" & IDs)
        End With
'imagine data in Worksheet B are in the first column
        On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To IDs
                Set fVal = rngDB.Find(vDB(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If fVal Is Nothing Then
                        Err.Clear
                        X.Add vDB(i, 1), CStr(vDB(i, 1))
                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            n = n + 1
                            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                            vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
            Next i
            Set rngT = Data.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If n > 0 Then
                rngT.Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now and I will do my best to study your code and learn from it. However, there is still a problem, that since it compares the new values with the original range on the Worksheet B, it pastes all the new values duplicated. For example value "100" is not on Worksheet B, so it pastes it on that sheet five times since it is five times on worksheet A. I would like to have it only once. I know I can now run a simple macro to delete duplicates, but is there any more elegant way to not paste some values more than once? Anyway big THX, you already solved my problem

Comment: @Petanek333: use new Collecton to remove duplicates. and modify my code.